# Using 2 sets of typedefs in Apollo

Tags: typescript, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo, apollo-server

I'm using ApolloServer on my Node env to run a server:

```js
// App.js

const express = require('express');
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express');
const resolvers = require('./resolvers.js');
const typeDefs = require('./schema');

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  resolvers,
  typeDefs,
});

async function startServer() {
    await apolloServer.start();
    const app = express();
    apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app });
    app.listen(4000, function () {
      console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000${apolloServer.graphqlPath}`)
    });
}

startServer();
```

The `ApolloServer` constructor takes a `typeDefs` argument:

```js
// schema.js

const { gql } = require('apollo-server-express');

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query{
    hello: String
  }
`;

module.exports = typeDefs;
```

But in my front-end client I also need to define the typeDefs to use in a query:

```js
// MyComponent

import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import { FC } from 'react';
import './MyComponent.css';
import typedefs from '../../server/typedefs'

interface MyComponentProps {}

const MyComponent: FC<MyComponentProps> = () => {
  const { data: hello, loading: isLoading } = useQuery(typedefs.Hello);

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div>Loading...</div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div className="MyComponent">
      data: {hello.hello}
    </div>
  )
}

export default MyComponent
```

```js
// typeDefs.ts

import {gql} from '@apollo/client';

const Hello = gql`
  query {
    hello
  }
`;

const queries = { Hello };

export default queries;
```

As you can see I define a typedef in both my Apollo Server schema and in my client typedef. This feel redundant but I'm unsure on how to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

I use the package codegen ([docs here](https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/))

Feel free to see one example of it working here in my [repo](https://github.com/WilliamPhilippe/wquestions-front/blob/main/codegen.yml).

Codegen will fetch your schema (with an HTTP call) and create generated types for you, like [here](https://github.com/WilliamPhilippe/wquestions-front/blob/main/src/types.d.ts).
Please, follow the documentation.

Comment: Codegen generates _types_ it doesn't seem to help with not having to define the GQL fields for both the back-end and the client.